# uniform convergence of $H^r$ projectors on compact sets?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ be a smooth, bounded domain. Let $(e_n)_{n\geq 0}\subset L^2(\Omega)$ be the Hilbert basis generated by the Dirichlet-Laplacian eigenfunctions, i-e $-\Delta e_n=\lambda_n e_n$ with zero boundary conditions.
We know that $\lambda_n\to+\infty$.

For $s\geq 0$ let me denote the "spectral" $H^s$ norm
$$
\|f\|^2_{H^s}=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0} \lambda_n^{s}|f_n|^2
\hspace{1cm}\mbox{for }f=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0} f_ne_n, 
$$
and finally for $N\geq 1$ let me denote the projector onto $E_N=span(e_0,\dots,e_{N-1})$ as
$$
P_N f=\sum\limits_{n\leq N-1} f_n e_n.
$$

---

**Fact 1**: for any fixed $f\in H^s$ there holds $(1-P_N)f\to 0$ in $H^s$, which can be stated as "$1-P_N\to 0$ pointwise on $H^s$". This is easy to check, since
$$
\|(1-P_N)f\|_{H^s}^2=\sum\limits_{n\geq N}|\lambda_n|^{s}|f_n|^2\to 0
$$
as the remainder of a convergent series.

---

**Fact 2**: for any $r<s$ there holds
$$
\|(1-P_N)f\|_{H^r}\leq \lambda_{N}^{(r-s)/2}\|f\|_{H^s},
$$
which can be stated as "$(1-P_N)\to 0$ in the $H^r$ norm uniformly on any $H^s$ ball."
Indeed, one can write immediately
$$
\|(1-P_N)f\|_{H^r}^2
=\sum\limits_{n\geq N}|\lambda_n|^{r-s}|\lambda_n|^s|f_n|^2
\leq |\lambda_N|^{r-s}\sum\limits_{n\geq N}|\lambda_n|^s|f_n|^2
\leq |\lambda_N|^{r-s} \|f\|_{H^s}^2
$$

---

> **Question:** can we extend the uniform convergence on arbitrary $H^r$-compact sets? More explicitly, is it true that
> $$
> \sup\limits_{f\in K}\|(1-P_N)f\|_{H^r}\to 0
> \qquad\mbox{as }N\to\infty
> $$
> for any $H^r$-compact set $K$? Fact 2 ecactly guarantees that this holds at least if $K$ is an $H^s$ ball, which is indeed $H^r$-compact classical Sobolev embedding since $r<s$. What about more generic compact sets?

I suspect this is well-known but for some reason I could not find anything on the subject (me not being a specialis in spectral analysis certainly does not help).

Comment: The Banach-Steinhaus theorem seems promising. Have you tried this?

Comment: If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of uniformly bounded, linear operators in a Banach space $X$ and $T_n x \to 0$ for every $x \in X$, then the convergence is uniform on a compact set $K$. Just fix $\epsilon>0$ and cover $K$ with a finite number of balls $B(x_i, \epsilon)$ and $\|T_n x\| \leq \|T_n(x-x_i)\|+\|T_n x_i\|$.

Comment: @LeoMoos: yes, of course this is the first thing that came to mind, but I couldn't make it work. Giorgio Metafune's comment seems to do the job, though.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : that works, I can't believe how simple the answer was... Please make this a proper answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It is fine that you get an answer to the question. No problem if it stays in the comments.

Comment: well, as you whish, but personally I like having answers accepted as such: of course not for the points/rewards, but just for future references as other users that may not take the time to navigate the comments. Just let me know if you change your mind.

Comment: Ok, I did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of uniformly bounded, linear operators in a Banach space $X$ nd $T_nx→0$ for every $x∈X$, then the convergence is uniform on a compact set $K$. Just fix $ϵ>0$ and cover $K$ with a finite number of balls $B(x_i,ϵ)$ and use $∥T_nx∥≤∥T_n(x−x_i)∥+∥T_n x_i∥$.

Comment: Just for the record: I realized this morning that this is not limited to linear equibounded operators: the proof works exactly the same for an equi-continuous family of possibly nonlinear functions. And I also realized that this is actually a variant of the Ascoli-Arzela theorem, where we already assume pointwise convergence (instead of pointwise relative compactness) and want to upgrade to uniform convergence.